# Deleting custom data type elements from an array based on their attributes

Tags: arrays, ruby, custom-data-attribute, custom-data-type

I'm making a calendar application and one of the functions is to allow the user to delete any preset activities of his choice. My current code gets the users input for their selected day, and displays all the pre set activities on that day. The user then inputs an activity name , and the code will loop to find an array element with data type attributes matching that activity name, and delete that element. The code works as long as there isnt more than one element with the same day as their day attribute, which is weird. Can anyone explain to me why this is so and how should i fix it?

Ive tried remodelling the code to use different syntax functions like reject and delete, but all come back to the same problem, which is that it will work unless there are two activities on the same day, e.g. if there are two activities with monday as a custom attribute of day, ruby will say that the element has and undefined class

```
def main
  # code inside my main function to get reminder_list
  puts "Wheeks Calendar App"
  # reads in data from text file and appends to an array
  text_file = File.new("wheeks.txt", "r")
  remind_no = text_file.gets.chomp.to_i
  reminder_list = Array.new
  for x in 0..(remind_no-1)
    reminder = read_reminder(text_file)
    reminder_list << reminder
  end
  text_file.close()
end

def delete_activities reminder_list
  # function to delete elements

  puts ("\n\nYou've chosen to delete activities")
  delete_day = (string_input("Please select a day to delete activities from")).capitalize
  days = ["Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday"]
  while !days.include?(delete_day)
    delete_day = (string_input("Please select a proper day")).capitalize
  end 
  puts "Displaying activities from " + delete_day + "\n\n"
  count = 0
  for x in 0..(reminder_list.length-1)
    if (reminder_list[x].day == delete_day)
      puts "Day:" + reminder_list[x].day
      puts "Start time:" + reminder_list[x].startTime.to_s
      puts "End time:" + reminder_list[x].endTime.to_s
      puts "Activity:" + reminder_list[x].activityName
      puts "Comments:" + reminder_list[x].activityComments
      puts "\n"
      count += 1
    end
  end
  if (count == 0)
    puts "There are no activities on that day\n\n"
  else
    delete_activity = (string_input("From the activities displayed, input the activity name of the activity you want to delete")).downcase
    for x in 0..(reminder_list.length-1)
      if (reminder_list[x].day == delete_day)
        if (reminder_list[x].activityName == delete_activity)
          reminder_list.delete_at(x)
          puts "Activity " + delete_activity + " has been deleted from " + delete_day + "\n\n"
        end 
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: From the code in the question it seems that you've a non-Ruby background. Most Ruby programmers don't use *for*-loops. I recommend taking a look [this article](https://jamesgolick.com/2008/1/5/an-introduction-to-ruby-s-enumerable-module.html), which introduces a few of the [Enumerable](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Enumerable.html) methods.

Comment: ah i see , thanks. Yea im from a python background haha, the links are useful thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

The problem I see is that you're looping through the indexes while deleting elements from the array. This causes the array elements to shift when the first item is removed, which in turn causes the loop to skip one element after one of the elements is removed.

I recommend using [`#reject!`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Array.html#method-i-reject-21):

```
delete_activity = string_input("From the activities displayed, input the activity name of the activity you want to delete").downcase

reminder_list.reject! do |activity|
  to_delete = activity.day == delete_day && activity.activityName == delete_activity

  if to_delete
    puts "Activity #{delete_activity} has been deleted from #{delete_day}\n\n"
  end

  to_delete
end
```

Or if you don't mind leaving out the the `puts` call.

```
reminder_list.reject! do |activity|
  activity.day == delete_day && activity.activityName == delete_activity
end
```

Comment: thank you very much, this code works, but do you mind answering a few questions i have? why does reject! not shift elements in an array even tho it deletes them as well? And what is the point of calling to_delete again at the end? finally is there a difference between puts #{delete_acitivity} and puts "activity" + delete_activity + "has been deleted" or is #{} just to declare variables in double quotation marks?

Comment: You'll have to view `reject!` as a blackbox. The method is specifically build to remove the elements from the array from whom the block returns a truthy value. Imagine it something like [this](https://gist.github.com/3limin4t0r/2a055d272508bf874e5c14cf9ecc1207). `to_delete` is called just before the end of the block to return the correct value. Otherwise the last statement would be the *if* statement, this statement contains only a `puts` call which always returns `nil`, meaning no elements would be removed from the array.

Comment: Last but not least the use of `"foo bar #{statement}"` in double quoted string context is practically the same as `"foo bar " + statement` with the only difference that `#to_s` is called if the provided statement does not result in a string. `"foo bar #{Object.new}" #=> "foo bar #<Object:0x0055a48e392168>"` while `"foo bar " + Object.new #=> TypeError: no implicit conversion of Object into String`